# Java: is it possible to create two objects during different runtimes (different JVMs) with the same identity?

Tags: db4o, serializable, object-oriented-database

I am using DB4o and want to make sure I get one unique object back when I use code like this:

```
  public List<Object> getListOfObjects(final Object o){

        List<Object> result = db.query(new Predicate<Object>(){

          @Override
          public boolean match (Object arg0){

             if(arg0.equals(o)){
                return true;
              }
            else{
                return false;
             }
        });

        return result;
      }
```

The List object "result" desirably should have no more than 1 element. However, isn't it possible that Java creates objects with the same identities during different runtimes (different JVMs)? If that could occur then it would mess up my database.

**Surely there must be an answer to whether or not Java objects can have the same identities across JVMs.**

-Alex

Answer (score 1):

If you overwrite the .equals() method of your object, then its easy to have multiple instances of a object which is equals. The whole purpose of the equal() method is to compare two objects about the 'semantic/content" equality. It does not quarantine any uniqueness.

Now if you do not override any equal method, then the object identity is compared. (like using the == operator). The identity is unique in a JVM and there are never two objects with the same identity.

Btw/Offtopic: If you store thousands of object in db4o and use your query, it will be quite slow. More about that [here](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/basics/querying/native_queries/nq_performance_characteristics.htm).

Comment: Yes thank you, I like what you have stated. But my question was asking if the identities (==) of different objects could be the same across two different JVMs....I assume for now that this is true.